# Provide Support for WP Hooks in Custom Plugin

Tags: wordpress, hook

***Some wordpress captcha plugin use login_form hook to add their fields. Is it possible to provide support for login_form hook in my plugin's custom form? It means if someone use this hook to add their work it will reflect on my custom plugin's form so that i can get befefit from this.***

Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. For example, through ACF form fields that are saved in the database and can used to fetched for another query through get_post_meta. Check this out: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/.